# Sending a Dynamic link through Email

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to use this code...

```
$message = '<a href="<?php echo curPageURL() ?> ">Click Here</a>';
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The reason why is I want to email the current page I am on with the data and hyperlink to an email.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$message = '<a href="' . curPageURL() . '">Click Here</a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already in a php tag (shown by you using $message), so you do not need to open another one when assigning its value.

```
$message = '<a href="'.curPageURL().'">Click Here</a>';
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

In PHP the `.` is the concatenator (it sticks two strings together).